# Test performing on counts

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

In R a dataset `data1` that contains `game` (that's a computergame) and `times`. There are 6 games and `times` simply tells us how many time a game has been played in `data1`. So `head(data1)` gives us

```
game  times
1     850
2     621
...
6     210
```

Similar for `data2` we get

```
game  times
1     744
2     989
...
6     711
```

And `sum(data1$times)` is a little higher than `sum(data2$times)`. We have about 2000 users in `data1` and about 1000 users in `data2` but I do not think that information is relevant.

I want to compare the two datasets and see if there is a statistically difference and which game  "causes" that difference.

Data1 contains game and the number of time they have been played by user's that are still active (meaning that they are still playing). Data2 contains games and the number of time they have been played by user's that are non-active, meaning that they don't play any more, they have stopped.

I want to investigate if there is a game that is 'bad' meaning that it somehow 'causes' users stop playing so they become inactive.

The data are collected on a computer every time they have played the games on their computer.

What test should I use two compare these. I don't think Pearson's `chisq.test` is the right choice in this case, maybe `wilcox.test` is the right to chose ?

Comment: Why is the chi-square the wrong choice? Explaining your reasoning may help us understand the issue.

Comment: Because chisq.test is uses in cases where we have successes vs. non-succeses.

Comment: Well, it is used in those cases, yes, but that's like saying clothes can't be blue because the sky is blue. The chi-square is used in situations that are not a success/no-success dichotomy.